# how do i save state or status transitions against a unique id in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and working on POC of a solution.
I have a use-case wherein i want to keep track of state changes of a ticket. The ticket id is the unique identifier for the data. I want to save the status changes, the time when status is changes and the comments on the ticket.

What is the best way to implement this?

I am saving my ticket data in an index with mapping defined as below:

```
"mappings": {
    "properties":
        {
            "ticket_id": { "type": "keyword" },
            "Problem Description": { "type": "text" },
            "start_time" :{"type": "date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},
            "end_time" :{"type": "date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},
            "workflow_status":{"type": "text" }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its difficult to visualise the problem and explain the solution without data, hence I created below data to explain it better:

**Index Sample data**

```
// below document doesn't marks the status to `done` hence just the `start_time` change with Description.

{
    "ticket_id" : "jira-001",
    "Problem_Description" : "this is first jira-001",
    "start_time" : "2022-09-14 05:30:00",
    "workflow_status" : "backlog"
}

// below document doesn't marks the status to `done` hence just the `start_time` change with Description.


{
    "ticket_id" : "jira-001",
    "Problem_Description" : "working on jira-001",
    "start_time" : "2022-09-14 07:30:00",
    "workflow_status" : "in-progress"
}

// below document marks the status to `done` hence `end_time` 
{
    "ticket_id" : "jira-001",
    "Problem_Description" : "completed jira-001",
    "start_time" : "2022-09-15 01:30:00",
    "end_time" : "2022-09-15 04:30:00",
    "workflow_status" : "done"
}
```

After that when you want to get all the workflow of same `ticket` `jira-001` in my example, you can use below query to fetch that sort based on their `start_time`

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "ticket_id": "jira-001"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "start_time": "asc"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will give below result, Hope this helps and is according to your use-case.

```
hits": [
            {
                "_index": "73706581",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "ticket_id": "jira-001",
                    "Problem_Description": "this is first jira-001",
                    "start_time": "2022-09-14 05:30:00",
                    "workflow_status": "backlog"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1663133400000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "73706581",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "ticket_id": "jira-001",
                    "Problem_Description": "working on jira-001",
                    "start_time": "2022-09-14 07:30:00",
                    "workflow_status": "in-progress"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1663140600000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "73706581",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "ticket_id": "jira-001",
                    "Problem_Description": "completed jira-001",
                    "start_time": "2022-09-15 01:30:00",
                    "end_time": "2022-09-15 04:30:00",
                    "workflow_status": "done"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1663205400000
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks you for creating a sample data and sharing the solution. Do you have any recommendation on using python's elasticsearch_dsl for creating methods to create a query?

Comment: @WW_ thanks for marking answer, you can use any official Elasticsearch client for creating the queries, I am not familier with python as I worked with their official Java client only.
Also please don't forget to upvote the answer as well.